# How do I resolve werkzeug.routing.BuildError?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have defined the jinja code as shown below,

```html
{% else %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ url_for('nextRecords', dataset=dataset,  begin=begin,
                        limit=limit) }}"><button class="uk-button" type="button">Next</button>    
    </a>
  </li>

{% endif %}
```

I have defined it's corresponding function as shown below,

```html
@app.route("/records/<string:dataset>/<int:start>/<int:limit>")
def nextRecords(dataset, start, limit):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route has a *`start`* parameter, but you used `begin` in the `url_for()` call.

The correct `url_for()` would be:

```
{{ url_for('nextRecords', dataset=dataset, start=begin, limit=limit) }}
```

Comment: But, when I used start in the Jinja, it threw UndefinedError

Comment: @MaheshKumarK: look closely. The Jinja `begin` parameter is being passed to the `start` keyword argument.